# How to merge git repos and maintain branches

Tags: git, git-merge

I have several git repos that I would like to merge into one. Is there a way to do this and maintain the branches? I don't want to merge just master branches.

Thanks

Comment: what does merging several repos actually mean? Do you mean `git submodule`

Comment: it means putting everything in those repos in the same (new) repo

Answer (score 0):

Merging repo can mean:

- [git submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules): you keep them as separate repos, but one parent repo register a precise SHA1 reference for each one in their own respective subfolders
- [git subtree merging](http://git-scm.com/book/ch6-7.html): you have only one repo (and one `master` branch), even though each of the subrepos are in their own subfolders.

Comment: I don't want separate repos so submodules won't work, but I don't want to lose my branches, so subtrees won't work either. I think what I want is not possible.